# Remove class from Viewchild Element after setTimeout in Angular2

Tags: angular

Hi I want to remove some classes from two elements but nothing happens with my code.

My html

```
<div class="d-flex ml-auto align-items-center animated fadeInRight faster" #outgoing>
  ...
</div>
<div class="d-flex ml-auto align-items-center animated fadeInLeft faster" #incoming>
  ...
</div>
```

In my component where i try to remove the classes `animated` `fadeInLeft` and `faster` from the elements after a second.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('outgoing', {static: false}) outgoingEl: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('incoming', {static: false}) incomingEl: ElementRef;


  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.outgoingEl.nativeElement, 'animated');
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.outgoingEl.nativeElement, 'fadeInRight');
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.outgoingEl.nativeElement, 'faster');

        this.renderer.removeClass(this.incomingEl.nativeElement, 'animated');
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.incomingEl.nativeElement, 'fadeInRight');
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.incomingEl.nativeElement, 'faster');
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? When inspecting the elements in Chrome Dev Tools the classes are not removed.

Comment: outgoingEl is already a native element.....can you try passing only this.outgoingEl to the removeClass method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't bother with renderer, use `ngClass`

```
<div class="d-flex ml-auto align-items-center" [ngClass]="outgoingClasses">
  ...
</div>
<div class="d-flex ml-auto align-items-center" [ngClass]="incomingClasses">
  ...
</div>


  outgoingClasses = { 'animated': true, 'fadeInRight': true, 'faster': true }
  incomingClasses = { 'animated': true, 'fadeInLeft': true, 'faster': true }
  ngOnInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.outgoingClasses = null;
        this.incomingClasses = null;
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

you could just define the variables like:

```
outgoingClasses = 'animated fadeInRight faster'
```

if that gets the job done, but you can add / remove individual classes in the object structure if you'd like more easily.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I did not thought of this! Good, easy and working.

Comment: gotta get into the angular mindset and outta the jquery mindset